# Lucene does not work for MUSTNOT Boolean query

Tags: java, lucene

I created a lucene indexes for set of data and trying to retrieve results from that.

When I do a boolean query with **SHOULD**, lucene returns me expected result.

```
 eg: (title:"america")
```

But on the other hand when I do a **MUST_NOT** query, it returns me **empty** results even though there are lot of data which satisfy this criteria.

```
(-title:"america")
```

I think I am doing some silly mistake but not able to figure it out so far. Could someone  please give some pointers.

Answer (score 1):

Understood the issue. I should combine MUSt NoT with some other operators.

Quote from https://www.bookdepository.com/Lucene-in-Action-Erik-Hatcher/9781933988177?redirected=true&utm_medium=Google&utm_campaign=Base3&utm_source=BE&utm_content=Lucene-in-Action&selectCurrency=EUR&w=AF4UAU960P6LMLA8VCZZ&gclid=Cj0KCQjwuL_8BRCXARIsAGiC51C8OdXsVpJbYRfodiFcGFEl2FKylqh2MvBjnHs9T5fVfMmDzZXbU4oaAisFEALw_wcB

> Placing a NOT in front of a term excludes documents matching the following term.
> Negating a term must be combined with at
> least one non-negated term to return docu-
> ments; in other words, it isn’t possible to
> use a query like NOT term to find all docu-
> ments that don’t contain a term.